# RMISecurityManager - load client.policy

Tags: java, rmi, securitymanager

I want to load SecurityManager policy from file client.policy.
I read that I could do it specifying -Djava.security.policy=client.policy.
But I don't want to specify this in command line.
I try to specify it in properties file.
Actually my code throw exception.
How could I read policy without command line arguments?

Here are fragments of my code:

```
prop.load(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
        prop.putAll(System.getProperties());//add Properties from command line

        RMISecurityManager rmi = new RMISecurityManager();
        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
            System.setSecurityManager(rmi);
        }

        //Connect to server by RMIRegistry
        rmiRegistryAddress = prop.getProperty("rmi.registryaddress");
        logger.info("Klient: serwer szukany pod adresem: "+rmiRegistryAddress);
        ISerwer serwer = (ISerwer) Naming.lookup(rmiRegistryAddress + "/" + SERWER_REMOTE_OBJECT_NAME);
```

config.properties:

```
    rmi.registryaddress = rmi://192.168.2.3:1099
    #java.rmi.server.codebase=http://...
    java.security.policy=client.policy
```

client.policy:

```
grant codeBase "file:src/" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

And exception:

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   ("java.net.SocketPermission" "192.168.2.3:1099" "connect,resolve")    at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
>     at
>   java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
>     at
>   java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
>     at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1051)
>     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:574)     at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)  at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:425)   at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:208)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:147)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
>     at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:341)   at
>   sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:101)   at
>   sr.warcaby.klient.Klient.run(Klient.java:88)  at
>   sr.warcaby.klient.Klient.main(Klient.java:73)

It appears that client.policy file is somehow not readed.

Second question: How to grant all permissions to local code? This path ("file:src/") not works. I want to set relative path.

Edit:

I have done some changes.
Now program works but not as I want.
It gives all permission to code from remote codebase but I want give only some permission to remote code.

Changes:

`System.setProperties(prop);`

`grant codeBase "file:/-" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};`

`java.security.policy=src/main/resources/client.policy
java.rmi.server.codebase=http://...somehttpaddress.../warcabycodebase-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

Comment: I have one more problem.
The client policy is working when I launch classes from Eclipse. But when I create jar that contains client.policy and when I run this jar, client.policy is not working.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing here that actually sets the contents of your .properties file as the system properties.

NB You need to set `java.security.policy` *before* you install the security manager.

And you don't need to install a security manager at all unless you are using the RMI codebase feature, with classes supplied by the server.

Comment: Do you have the codebase classes also available locally? If so, they won't be loaded from the codebase and willl have the corresponding permissions.